# Automating javascript confirmation box

Tags: javascript

As is known, when a javascript confirmation alert/box pops up, the browser focuses on the box leaving everything else disabled until one of two options are chosen, when "OK" is clicked it returns true, when "Cancel" is clicked it returns false.

Now when writing scripts that involve confirmation alerts, my statements are based on the return of these booleans, now I am wondering (I do not know if this is a dumb question), ist here a way in javascript alone to force or automate the return of either true or false?

For instance, I write a script to detect a confirmation alert, and then force it to return true or false in my script.

Note: I am a mere beginner in javascript, so I do not know if this is a good question or not, but I would appreciate an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to open a confirmation box and then click it yourself?

Comment: Nope. You would use a, HTML+JavaScript dialog instead, E.g. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Comment: Is this for functional automated testing? If so use a library like selenium-webdriverjs or other.

Comment: @Liam It is something that I do everyday, so I am thinking of trying to automate it, like automating logins.

Answer (score 3):

Not from within the page.

JavaScript is single threaded and `confirm` and `alert` are blocking. No JS will run while they are waiting for input.

If you were, for instance, writing tests for this, then you could try mocking the entire `confirm` or `alert` function.

```js
window.confirmValue = true;
window.confirm = function () { return window.confirmValue; }

if (confirm("Hello, world")) {
  console.log("True");
}
```

If you were writing JS from outside the page (e.g. to drive PhantomJS) then the approach might be different.