# Manage Dialogbox in the Webview2 (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I would like to manage the dialogbox generated by the webview2.
Example : Confirm a command or download.

I saw that maybe it was the CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening event. But I don't know how to use it.
So, have you an example because I don't find this Event in WPF

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The WebView2 control doesn't expose the same APIs that CoreWebView2 does. Instead the WebView2 exposes some basic APIs that CoreWebView2 does and for the rest it exposes its CoreWebView2 object via its CoreWebView2 property. This property is non-null after the WebView2 control has been initialized by awaiting the EnsureCoreWebView2Async method or the CoreWebView2Ready event is raised. You can read more about the [WebView2 control initializing the CoreWebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.664.37#remarks) in our docs.

So you can find the event on `webView2.CoreWebView2.ScriptDialogOpening` after the CoreWebView2 is initialized

Comment: Is it possible to detect dialogbox openning and valide the action button with a addEventListener.?

Comment: When I do :

     functionString = 
  
  String.Format("document.getElementById('actionUpdateSoftwareVersionSubmit').click()")

     result = Await webview_Cockpit.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(functionString)

The htm page return a dialogbox. Here is the html code.

    <input id="actionUpdateSoftwareVersionSubmit" class="submitButton" type="submit" 
    value="Valider" onclick="return validateAndShowLoader('Confirm the update 
    request');">

So I would want Confirm the command by my application

Comment: I found the solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814031/automating-javascript-confirmation-box